# Genesis 4:15, "whosoever" or "anyone"?

Tags: genesis, word-study, hebrew-bible

Genesis 4:15 (DRB):

> And the Lord said to him: No, it shall not be so: but **whosoever** shall kill Cain, shall be punished sevenfold. And the Lord set a mark upon Cain, that whosoever found him should not kill him.

I am not expert in English, but to my knowledge, isn't "whosoever" means "every one who"?

The verse Genesis 4:15 has about 4 translations:

- anyone.
- any one.
- whoever.
- whosoever.

In case of "anyone", it is accepted logically.

But in case of "whosoever" which means "every one" this means that Cain will be killed many times by many persons. This means killing Cain is allegorical.

There's difference between:

- Anyone who kills Cain shall be punished...
- Every one who kills Cain shall be punished...

There's logical difference between (anyone) and (every one).

So, please correct me if I am wrong. I hope you give me the accurate English translation of this verse.

Comment: You're overthinking it. There's no real difference in this context. Whether it's one person or a bunch of people killed him together, God's decree would apply to them all.

Comment: @curiousdannii I said: correct me if I am wrong. For me, there is logical difference between (anyone) and (every one), they are not equal.

Comment: They are all equivalent meanings in English.

Comment: @Dottard (anyone will do this will be punished), here I expect that mostly "no one" will do this. But (every one will do this will be punished), here I expect that mostly "many persons" will do this, time after time. I hope you understand me.

Comment: @Dottard one of the many functions of the Holy Books is to fix, amend the logic of the persons by applying practical logic examples.

Comment: The Bible is a book to teach us about God, nothing more.  It was written in ordinary language (of the time) and so has the normal linguistic idiom as part of it.  The way to understand the Bible is to simply ask what the passage would have meant to a person at the time.

Comment: @Dottard to know about God you should be mentally qualified to know about God, so, you should amend your logic. Amending logic is one of the functions of the Holy Books. To hear God you should be able to understand God.

Comment: Your question is not about logic - it is about simple English grammar.  Spiritual enlightenment is as per the Holy Spirit - see John 16:13.

Comment: @Dottard it is not about God speaking to us, it's about (us speaking to God). God speaking to Humanity is so easy, but Humanity speaking to God is the miracle. I asked about the difference between "anyone" and "whosoever" and about the accurate translation. To choose the accurate word you should admit first that there's logical difference.

Answer (score 2):

The Hebrew is לָכֵן֙ כָּל־הֹרֵ֣ג קַ֔יִן (therefore all who kill Cain).  The way the particle הֹרֵ֣ג is used translates to a limiting relative clause in English.  Because *all* is limited by the relative clause, there is no difference between *all who, anyone who, whoever,* and *whosoever*.  The clause "who kills Cain" makes them logically equivalent.  However because הֹרֵ֣ג is singular, *anyone who* and *whoever* are more grammatically correct.  *Whosoever* is no longer used in modern English, unless you're a lawyer.

Comment: I think: all who, every one who=anyone who, from all perspectives, is a logical error in English. This logical error is found also in Arabic: أيّ من=كلّ من. We may accept this equality bypass but upon checking, the equality is illogical.

Comment: Hebrew and Arabic are very similar languages.